# How to create an Area plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, stacked-area-chart

Is there any way to create an Area plot in Seaborn. I checked the documentation but  I couldn't able to find it.

Here is the data that I want to plot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'launch_year': [1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1957, 1958, 1959,
                        1960, 1961, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961],
        'state_code': ['China', 'China', 'China', 'China', 'China', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France',
                       'France', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Russia', 'Russia', 'Russia',
                       'Russia', 'Russia', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States'],
        'value': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 22, 18, 29, 41]}

# create a long format DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# pivot the DataFrame to a wide format
year_countries = df.pivot(index='launch_year', columns='state_code', values='value')

# display(year_countries)

state_code   China  France  Japan  Russia  United States
launch_year                                             
1957             0       0      0       2              1
1958             0       0      0       5             22
1959             0       0      0       4             18
1960             0       0      0       8             29
1961             0       0      0       9             41
```

I created a line plot using this code -

```
sns.relplot(data=year_countries, kind='line',
            height=7, aspect=1.3,linestyle='solid')

plt.xlabel('Lanuch Year', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of Launches', fontsize=15)
plt.title('Space Launches By Country',fontsize=17)

plt.show()
```

but the Plot isn't so clear when using a line chart

[image: Plot fig]

Also can't able to make the lines Solid and Sort the legends based on the values in descending order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with [`kind='area'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.area.html).

Setting a `seaborn` style with `plt.style.use('seaborn')` is deprecated.

In addition, you need to manually sort the legend, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27512450). However, changing the legend order does not change the plot order.

`xticks=range(1957, 1962)` can be used to specify the `xticks`, otherwise the `'launch_year'` is treated as floats on the `x-axis`

[image]

**Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.2`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`**

```
ax = year_countries.plot(kind='area', figsize=(9, 6), xticks=range(1957, 1962))
ax.set_xlabel('Launch Year', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Launches', fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Space Launches By Country', fontsize=17)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels, handles = zip(*sorted(zip(labels, handles), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True))
ax.legend(handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) to set the order of the columns in `df`, prior to pivoting. This will ensure the plot order and legend order are the same (e.g. the first group in the legend is the first group in the plot stack).

```py
# set the order of the column in df
df.state_code = pd.Categorical(df.state_code, sorted(df.state_code.unique())[::-1], ordered=True)

# now pivot df
year_countries = df.pivot(index='launch_year', columns='state_code', values='value')

# plot
ax = year_countries.plot(kind='area', figsize=(9, 6), xticks=range(1957, 1962))
ax.set_xlabel('Launch Year', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Launches', fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Space Launches By Country', fontsize=17)

# move the legend
ax.legend(title='Countries', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

[image]