# Matplotlib's legend: how to order entries by row first, rather than by column

Tags: python, matplotlib

By default Matplotlib orders the entries in the legend by column, e.g.,

```
In [48]: from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show
    ...: f, ax = subplots(figsize=(6, 2), constrained_layout=True)
    ...: for i in range(1, 10):
    ...:     ax.plot((0,1),(0,1), label=str(i))
    ...: ax.legend(ncol=4, loc=3)
    ...: show()
```

[image]

but I'd like better to have the entries listed by rows, like

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9
```

I could reorder the handles and labels and invoke `ax.legend` passing the reordered lists (I'll post that as an answer if requested in comments) but *I'd like to know if there is a more direct and straightforward way to instruct Matplotlib to do as I want*, so that I don't have to copy and paste the reorder solution in 50% of the Matplotlib scripts I'll write…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22276133/6361531  I am afraid you might have to manually order your legend handlers.

Comment: Yes, please, I'd like to see your reorder solution.

Comment: @ScottBoston directly from the mouth of T.A. Caswell, ok, ok! I'll do it manually…

Comment: That is an old post 2014.  I was looking in the recent version of the API documentation and I haven't found any help yet.

Comment: Even a reddit post 2 years ago https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8zbbql/changing_order_of_items_in_legend_matplotlibpyplot/

Comment: Btw.. great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lists of handles to artists and the labels using the Axes method `get_legend_handles_labels`, then you call `legend` passing the reordered lists.

To reorder the lists, we observe that

- `legend` places in the first column the first elements in the lists, then proceeds with the following columns/items,
- the columns have variable lengths but all the rows must have the same length (i.e., `ncol`) except the last one, moreover in each column the increment betweeen items must equal `ncol`.

That said, it is possible to generate a sublist for each column using slicing, the length of the column is automatically the right one..., and eventually use `sum` to join the sub lists in the reordered one.

```
In [59]: from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show
    ...: reorder = lambda l, nc: sum((l[i::nc] for i in range(nc)), [])
    ...: 
    ...: f, ax = subplots(figsize=(6, 2), constrained_layout=True)
    ...: for i in range(1, 10):
    ...:     ax.plot((0,1),(0,1), label=str(i))
    ...: h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ...: ax.legend(reorder(h, 4), reorder(l, 4), ncol=4, loc=3)
    ...: show()
```

[image]

---

*A few years later...*

---

Slightly more compact in its usage when calling `legend`

```
reorder=lambda hl,nc:(sum((lis[i::nc]for i in range(nc)),[])for lis in hl)
...
h_l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(*reorder(h_l, 4), ncol=4)
```

(but you must remember to *unpack* the values returned by `reorder`).