Pyplot Printing All Bars Overlapping in First Position in Grouped Bar Chart
I'm generating a grouped bar chart showing what orders are ordered to arrive on what day of the week.  My code is as follows:
plt.figure(1)
x = np.arange(7)
width = .1
for j in range(9):
    print(pdChart[j])
    plt.bar((j-4)/10, pdChart[j], width, label=list(flavors.keys())[j])

plt.xticks(x,daysOWeek) 
plt.ylabel("Orders")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Preferred Delivery Days")
plt.show()

However, it's printing everything in the Monday position.  So the output is only "Monday" data with the highest day's total appearing as the bar height for each flavor.  The individual bars are aligned properly and all that.  But there's nothing for Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.
[420 352 425 391 423 388 387]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[857 840 881 900 852 851 874]
[248 234 246 239 242 223 249]
[235 243 227 249 270 251 249]
[1670 1822 1835 1818 1796 1804 1764]
[427 461 430 490 428 435 444]
[102 101  94  86 102 110 107]
[718 743 718 705 741 781 716]

So the data is right.  But instead of seven bars per line, I get one that's 425, 0, 900, 249, etc. only appearing to show the highest day total for the week, which is why I assume it's overlapping.

The first arg of plt.bar() should be an array with all your values precomputed. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/pyplot.html#plotting-with-categorical-variables for more information

Even for a grouped chart?  Everything I see starts with alignment for grouped.  I've been working from  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-grouped-bar-plot-in-matplotlib/  Also, the data is correct; it's just in the wrong place.

The for loop is the problem for your grouped chart. Even in the link you provided there is not a single for loop.

I'm using that because I'm doing nine datasets.  And that part is working.  Here's the output https://imgur.com/a/bZ3aAIu

Thanks for the screenshot, I get it. The thing I like to do in these cases is to at least reproduce the example. Or by starting from the example and tweaking it until I get the result I want , or by decomposing the code I made to make it look like the example. The only difference I see is the delta between all the x's is it is by 0.2. And in yours it's by 0.1, try to divide by 5 instead of 10 in the first arg.

Good call on recreating the example.  I'll check that out tomorrow.  Thanks for your help!

You're welcome, I hope you'll find the answer !


You use a scalar value for the positioning of all the bars for a flavour — use an array of values instead
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

flavors = 'Vanilla+Caramel Swirl,Chocolate+Peanut Butter,Strawberry+Cheesecake,Mint+Chocolate Chips,Cookies+Cream,Coffee+Toffee,Mango+Coconut,Pistachio+Almond,Brownie+Fudge'.split(',')
pdChart = [[420,352,425,391,423,388,387],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[857,840,881,900,852,851,874],[248,234,246,239,242,223,249],[235,243,227,249,270,251,249],[1670,1822,1835,1818,1796,1804,1764],[427,461,430,490,428,435,444],[102,101,94,86,102,110,107],[718,743,718,705,741,781,716]]

# when drawing the bars for the weekdays, we need to move the reference point
weekday = np.arange(7)
# to place the bars, we need the position of each bar wrt the day position,
# here we want to center the bars about the x-tick
N = len(flavors)
i_center = N/2
# then the shift of each bar wrt to the x-tick and the width of each bar
# the shift × N must be less than 1 otherwise the bars are "continuous"
shift = 1/(N+3)
# the width of each bar must be less than the shift if we want a separation
width = 1/(N+5)

for i, (flavor, orders) in enumerate(zip(flavors, pdChart)):
    plt.bar(weekday+shift*(i-i_center), orders, label=flavor, width=width)

# fill legend rows first, ty https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783666/2749397
reorder = lambda hl,nc:(sum((lis[i::nc]for i in range(nc)),[])for lis in hl)
hl = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(*reorder(hl, 3), ncol=3, loc=(0, 1.04), fontsize='x-small')

plt.xticks(weekday, 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split());
plt.gcf().set_layout_engine('constrained')
plt.show()


That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!
