# Matplotlib: order of legend entries

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have recently discovered matplotlib as a much better alternative to Matlab for plots. Unfortunately, my knowledge of python is close to zero.

Considering the following minimal working example: I would like the entries in the legend to appear in the order in which they are declared. I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263807/how-is-order-of-items-in-matplotlib-legend-determined) that the entries are ordered first based on type and then based on order (in this case, the two line plots always come before the scatter plot).

I tried to apply the methods from the above post to my example, i.e., creating handles and passing them to `plt.legend`, but it doesn't work. Unfortunately, I'm doing it quite blindly as I don't fully understand what I'm doing, so it might be the wrong approach or some syntax error. How would one adapt the simple code below to enforce the desired legend order?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': True})

plt.scatter([1, 2, 3], [5, 10, 15], label='1st entry')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], label='2nd entry')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], label='3st entry')

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='lower right', labelspacing=0.25, handlelength=0.4, handletextpad=0.7)

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution (but I don't find it very elegant) that consists in reordering the legend after it has been automatically generated by matplotlib:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': True})

ax.scatter([1, 2, 3], [5, 10, 15], label='1st entry')
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], label='2nd entry')
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], label='3rd entry')

ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = [handles[2], handles[0], handles[1]]
labels = [labels[2], labels[0], labels[1]]

ax.legend(handles,labels,loc='lower right', labelspacing=0.25, handlelength=0.4, handletextpad=0.7)
```

EDIT: in a comment, OP asks for a version without creating an axis explicitly, here it is (but I would advise getting used to working with axis for making more advanced plots):

```py
plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': True})

plt.scatter([1, 2, 3], [5, 10, 15], label='1st entry')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], label='2nd entry')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], label='3rd entry')

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

handles,labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = [handles[2], handles[0], handles[1]]
labels = [labels[2], labels[0], labels[1]]

plt.legend(handles,labels,loc='lower right', labelspacing=0.25, handlelength=0.4, handletextpad=0.7)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do the same without replacing "plt." with "ax." everywhere?

Comment: `handles[::-1]`You can specify the list in reverse order like this.

Comment: @TheDon I edited my answer to add a version without explicit use of the axis variable, but I would advise getting used to it for the next steps of your journey using matplotlib ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I'd really appreciate if you could explain (very briefly) why I should work with "ax." instead of "plt.".

Comment: Very briefly: using `plt.` works perfectly for a quick single plot, but as soon as you will want to fine-tune it, or add a second plot under or next to your first one for context, it will be much easier with `ax.`. That's why, even for single plots, I now use `ax.`, so that it is easy to augment from there. But it might be a very personal approach ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take it into consideration :)